# Is it possible to create a soundproof studio in an apartment?

Tags: home-studio, studio

I have a 70 square meters building apartment, and two pretty decent rooms i could use as a studio. Is it possible to soundproof that good that it's possible to play drums and amplified guitars without it being noisy in other apartments?

Comment: Depends what you mean by noisy... but very unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're able to spend enough money, anything is possible.

The ideal solution in this case would be to build an isolated room within a room. Using offset studs, so inside and outside walls hang from separate studs, double sheetrock, green glue, and heavy insulation in all walls, including floor and ceiling. This is the technique used in most production facilities to achieve high isolation between the control room and live room.

Whether or not you can do this in your apartment is up to your landlord. You maybe be better off renting a dedicated rehearsal facility.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to be possible for less than tens of thousands of dollars.  Even if you have free reign to modify the building as needed, it's still generally easily 5 to 10 grand just to soundproof a room well.  In order to do that when you can't modify the building extensively, you'd basically have to build your own isolated room and then soundproof that.  That isn't going to be cheap at all.